# add custom icons to google maps nearby places

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I got to get my location and nearby places I want in `google maps`.

I just cant seem to figure out how to add custom icons (markers) to the nearby places.

I'm new to JS so any help plz!

```
1. /////MY CODE/////



     <!DOCTYPE html> <html>   <head>
            <title>Geolocation</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <style>
              html, body, #map {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px
              }
            </style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCAVlwiMJEZaezI2EJvmL5peK4wS3gkFGo&sensor=true"></script>-->





<script>
               var infowindow,
                placemarkers = [];


      function placeSearch(map, request) {
          var map = map;
          var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
          service.search(request,

          function (results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
                      bounds.extend(results[i].geometry.location);
                      placemarkers.push(createMarker(results[i].geometry.location,
                      map,
    !!!!this is the places icons. i want to change these icons to custom
icons!!!!!'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_orange.png',
                      results[i].name,
                      false, {
                          fnc: function () {
                              infowindow.open();
                          }

                      }));
                  }
                  map.fitBounds(bounds);
              }
          });

      }

      function createMarker(latlng, map, icon, content, center, action) {

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              position: latlng,
              content: content,
          });
          ////////toggle bounce////
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);

          function toggleBounce() {

            if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
            marker.setAnimation(null);
        } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);   } } ///////bounce end////

          if (icon) {
              marker.setIcon(icon);
          }

          if (center) {
              map.setCenter(latlng);
          }

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
              infowindow.setContent(this.content);
              infowindow.open(map, this);
          });

          if (action) {
              action.fnc(map, action.args);
          }
          return marker;
      }

      function initialize() {

          var location = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316),
              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                  center: location,
                  zoom: 15,
              });


          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (place) {
              createMarker(
              new google.maps.LatLng(place.coords.latitude,
              place.coords.longitude),
              map,
              null,
                  'your current position',
              true, {
                  fnc: placeSearch,
                  args: {
                      radius: 5000,
                      types: ['grocery_or_supermarket'],
                      location: new google.maps.LatLng(place.coords.latitude,
                      place.coords.longitude)
                  }
              });
          });
      }

    </script>   </head>   <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map"> </div>   </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    var infowindow,
     placemarkers = [];
    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
    var icons = {
        parking: {
            icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
        },
        library: {
            icon: iconBase + 'library_maps.png'
        },
        info: {
            icon: iconBase + 'info-i_maps.png'
        },
        grocery_or_supermarket: {
            icon: iconBase + 'convenience.png'
        }
    };

    function placeSearch(map, request) {
        var map = map;
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.search(request,

        function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
                    bounds.extend(results[i].geometry.location);
                    placemarkers.push(createMarker(results[i].geometry.location,
                    map,
                    icons['grocery_or_supermarket'].icon,
                    results[i].name,
                    false, {
                        fnc: function () {
                            infowindow.open();
                        }

                    }));
                }
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
            }
        });

    }

    function createMarker(latlng, map, icon, content, center, action) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: latlng,
            content: content
        });
        ////////toggle bounce////
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);

        function toggleBounce() {

            if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
                marker.setAnimation(null);
            } else {
                marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);   } } ///////bounce end////

        if (icon) {
            marker.setIcon(icon);
        }

        if (center) {
            map.setCenter(latlng);
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent(this.content);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });

        if (action) {
            action.fnc(map, action.args);
        }
        return marker;
    }

    function initialize() {

        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316),
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: location,
                zoom: 15,
            });


        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (place) {
            createMarker(
            new google.maps.LatLng(place.coords.latitude,
            place.coords.longitude),
            map,
            null,
                'your current position',
            true, {
                fnc: placeSearch,
                args: {
                    radius: 5000,
                    types: ['grocery_or_supermarket'],
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(place.coords.latitude,
                    place.coords.longitude)
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: i tried that earlier but where to put it in my code i just cant seem toe figure it out.

Comment: okay but what happens with this part??

function (results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
                  bounds.extend(results[i].geometry.location);
                  placemarkers.push(createMarker(results[i].geometry.location,
                  map,
'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_orange.png', results[i].name, false, { fnc: function () { infowindow.open(); }

Comment: nope.

it breaks my current location and nearby places.
so nothing is happening now.

Comment: the nearby places markers are not being created in the createMarker function.

its being created in function (results, status)...

Comment: OK let me try and come up with a solution for you, give me a few minutes.

Comment: OK I have your code working, now let me try to edit it for custom icons, give me a few more minutes.

Comment: Bro...you legend thanks alot i cant believe it was that simple.

Comment: Cool I'm so glad it helped you!  Google Maps API is super fun!

Comment: i might need some more help if you can. more complex.

Comment: Best to start a new question and I'll take a look.